# SQL Aggregate Fraction

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with City and ComplaintType.

I am trying to create a normalization column that has the following computation:

> (pseudo) select number of a particular type in a particular city) / (number of all complaints in a particular city

I currently have the following SQL:

```
SELECT City AS city_name, ComplaintType AS complaint_type, 
    count(*) / (SELECT count(City) FROM data GROUP BY City) AS complaint_frac,
    count(*) AS count_freq,
    (SELECT count(City) FROM data GROUP BY City) AS count_city
FROM data
GROUP BY City, ComplaintType
ORDER BY complaint_frac DESC
```

Which gives me the following table:

[image]

The total complaints in a city (`count_city`) is incorrect. However, when I run the count_city query on it's own, the counts are correct and give the following output:

[image]

How do I correctly get my `city_count` associated with the number of `x` complaints by city so I can compute the correct fraction?

Cold hard numbers example:

> Bronx & Hot Water = 79690
>
> Bronx (total complaints) = 579363
>
> complaint_frac = 79690 / 579363 = 0.13754761695

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correlate your `subquery` in your main table.

```
SELECT City AS city_name, ComplaintType AS complaint_type, 
    count(*) / (SELECT count(City) FROM data GROUP BY City) AS complaint_frac,
    count(*) AS count_freq,
    (SELECT count(d1.City) FROM data d1 WHERE d1.City = d2.City GROUP BY d1.City) AS count_city
FROM data d2
GROUP BY City, ComplaintType
ORDER BY complaint_frac DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need subqueries for this, at least in MySQL 8+; window functions do the work:

```
SELECT City AS city_name, ComplaintType AS complaint_type,
       count(*) / sum(count(*)) over (partition by city) as complaint_frac,
       count(*) as count_freq,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by city) as count_city 
FROM data
GROUP BY City, ComplaintType
ORDER BY complaint_frac DESC
```